# ¿Como obtengo la posición n de una arreglo que está dentro de un ArrayList?

Tags: java

En caso de que quisiera obtener la posición 1 de un arreglo que está en un ArrayList ¿como puedo hacerlo?

```
public boolean esGanador() {
    ArrayList<int[]> lineas = new ArrayList<>();
    //Horizontales
    lineas.add(new int[]{0, 1, 2});
    lineas.add(new int[]{3, 4, 5});
    lineas.add(new int[]{6, 7, 8});
    //Verticales
    lineas.add(new int[]{0, 3, 6});
    lineas.add(new int[]{1, 4, 7});
    lineas.add(new int[]{2, 5, 8});
    //Diagonales
    lineas.add(new int[]{0, 4, 8});
    lineas.add(new int[]{2, 4, 6});


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener el elemento o valor que hay en un determinado índice de `ArrayList`, existe [el método `get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)).

En tu caso, dado que dentro de `lineas` hay a su vez arrays de números en cada posición, tendrías que indicar luego el índice del valor que quieres obtener una vez obtenido el elemento de la posición 0 (no la uno, porque los arrays empiezan en la posición 0).

Por ejemplo:

```
int [] theLine=lineas.get(0);
System.out.println("El valor es: "+ theLine[0]); //0
System.out.println("El valor es: "+ theLine[1]); //1
System.out.println("El valor es: "+ theLine[2]); //2
```

También puedes hacerlo así:

```
System.out.println("El valor es: "+ lineas.get(0)[0]); //0
System.out.println("El valor es: "+ lineas.get(0)[1]); //1
System.out.println("El valor es: "+ lineas.get(0)[2]); //2
```

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Como obtengo la posición n de una arreglo que está dentro de un
>   ArrayList?

La posición dentro de un arreglo de elementos esta determinada por su indice, iniciando en 0:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para obtener el valor de un elemento en el `ArrayList` usa el método [get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-)

> **[get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-)**: Devuelve el elemento en la posición especificada en esta lista.

Por lo tanto de esta forma obtendrías el primer elemento del ArrayList ( indice 0):

```
//Obtiene el primer elemento del ArrayList.
int[] primerElemento = lineas.get(0);

//Imprime contenido (opcional)
System.out.println("primerElemento contiene : " + Arrays.toString(primerElemento));
```

Si deseas a su ves obtener el primer elemento de este Array vuelve a usar el indice para obtener el primer elemento (indice 0):

```
System.out.println("El valor del primer elemento de primerElemento  es: "+ primerElemento[0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes obtener algún objeto dentro del ArrayList `lineas` con un get, por ejemplo `lineas.get(0)` y ahí tienes el primer objeto de tu array, ahora como tu objeto es un array primitivo, para obtener los elementos dentro de ese array primitivo tienes que usar los corchetes, entonces si quiero tomar el primer elemento de ese array, entonces haría `int primer_elemento = lineas.get(0)[0]`, con eso puedes empezar.